# Abap change pointers send complete material master data idoc

Tags: abap, sap-erp, idoc

I have change pointers set-up for material master data and it is already working. Now, I have the requirement always send the whole material information to the external system. When doing manually in BD10, I can select the option to send the full material. However, when using change pointers and the program RBDMIDOC, there does not seem to be a proper way to do it.

I have searched around and the solutions seem to be creating a custom program (copy of RBDMIDOC) which implements the logic to manually change the table BCDP to fool the system to send the full material information. 
This does not look like a good solution.

Any advise how this requirement can be realized "properly"? I don't think I am the first to have this requirement...

Thanks a lot for your answer(s)!

Comment: Are you looking for a non-programming solution?

Comment: @vwegert No, I don't mind. I already implemented BAPI BDCP_BEFORE_WRITE. Obviously, I want a way without making a system modification.

Comment: Sorry, can't help you there - I don't even have a table named BCDP in my system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution was to set the fldname in the change pointers to the special value of "ALELISTING". This will cause the system to send the whole material master data via the IDoc. Note that this might only work for material master data but not other IDocs.